# Error on "docker-compose" when I use by pipe with sh ( echo "docker-compose... " | sh )

Tags: python, docker, pipe, sh, docker-compose

I've a application which has multi container.
to easy installation, I decide to use packaging image. 
what I expected is like below

```
$ docker run my_application install | sh
```

-> pull all related images from registry

```
$ docker run my_application up | sh
```

-> do some initial job and up all of containers

But I'm stucked with below problem.

```
$ echo "docker-compose exec cassandra cqlsh -e 'desc keyspaces'" | sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 57, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 108, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 353, in exec_command
  File ".tox/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dockerpty/pty.py", line 338, in start
  File ".tox/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dockerpty/io.py", line 32, in set_blocking
ValueError: file descriptor cannot be a negative integer (-1)
docker-compose returned -1
```

error raised from docker-compose.
when trying like below, it works well.

```
$ echo "docker exec my_application_cassandra_1 cqlsh -e 'desc keyspaces'" | sh

system_traces  system

$ sh -c "docker-compose exec cassandra cqlsh -e 'desc keyspaces'"

system_traces  system
```

but when I use pipe with docker-compose 
it always put the error.

Does someone have any idea how I can handle this ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, when piping `docker-compose` output via gzip to a file. When I run the command myself in Bash, it works just fine. However, as a cron job, I'm getting the same error as you — and the same stack trace file & line numbers & function names, as you, and return code -1. Here's the command: `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose exec postgres pg_dumpall --username=postgres | gzip > $postgres_backup_path`  (I have that line in a backup script that I run sometimes manually (works fine) and sometimes as a cron job (won't work)).

Comment: I've worked around my problem by calling Docker directly like so: `/usr/bin/docker exec edm_postgres_1 pg_dumpall --username=postgres | gzip > $postgres_backup_path` — works fine from both Cron and manually in Bash.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an [open bug](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3352) in docker-compose.

As a workaround, you can pass the `-T` option to `docker-compose exec`:

```
$ docker-compose exec --help
[...]
-T                Disable pseudo-tty allocation. By default `docker-compose exec`
                  allocates a TTY.
```

Answer (score 3):

I see the same problem when trying to export from postgres with:

```
docker-compose exec postgres pg_dumpall -U postgres | gzip > file.gz
```

Adding the `-T` option to `exec` didn't help as it stops the pipe from working. (Actually, I'm not sure the pg_dumpall command runs at all, but it doesn't error)

The temporary solution is to use docker itself, so you'll need to change the command and container name, as:

```
docker exec fullname_postgres_1 pg_dumpall -U postgres | gzip > file.gz
```

Comment: I also hit this bug when I redirect with `2>&1`

Comment: This solution becomes quite robust if you use `docker exec "$(docker-compose ps -q SERVICE)" COMMAND ARGS`. The embedded `ps -q`  command will print the exact container ID of SERVICE to stdout so you can be sure to execute in the correct container.